# Adding padding/boundary to Raphael path for leniency on mouseover events

Tags: raphael

Consider a path (which is a line) drawn out with Raphael with a mouseover event that sets the cursor to hover. For a thin path/line it is difficult to hover the mouse over that path.

Is there a way to add an invisible border/padding/boundary to the path so that it is easier to hover over the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really simple way to accomplish that would be as follows:

1. Duplicate the path you're using as a hover trigger with `element`.`clone`
2. Move the clone in front of the current path with `element`.`insertAfter`
3. Use `element`.`attr` to set the clone's opacity to just above 0, so that it is effectively invisible but still receives click events, and to have a stroke-width property equal to the original path's stroke-width + your desired margin;
4. Add your hover events to the cloned element.

This will give you a invisible path much thicker than the original that is capable of receiving mouse events in place of the original, thinner path.

I've mocked this up [here](http://voidblossom.com/tests/clickMargin.php), with a cursor property set so you'll see crosshairs when the mouse is over the surrogate path.

Comment: nice! Thank you for the elaborate and quick response!